# Fail to declare variable in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

This is the error I got when I try to run the query shown below:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE productCount INT DEFAULT 0' at line 1

I am using Mysql workbench on ubuntu

- MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Linux/Unix version 6.3.8 CE build 1228 (64 bit)
- Cairo Version: 1.15.10
- OS: Linux 5.3.0-47-generic
- CPU: 4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz (500.028MHz) - 15.53GiB RAM
- Distribution: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- Fips mode enabled: no

[image]

Comment: Please provide your code as text, not as images. Also, an explanation of what you are trying to do would help.

Comment: DECLARE productCount INT DEFAULT 0;

Comment: i also try that  @msg varchar(200);

Answer (score 3):

DECLARE only can be used in triggers,functions and stored procedures betewenn BEGIN and END see [mysql maual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-compound-statements.html)

If you want to  use a variable declare a user defined variable like @msg

```
use testdb;
SET @msg := 'testme if you can';
SET @testcount := 0;

SELECT @msg,@testcount + 1;
```

Result:

```
# @msg, @testcount + 1
testme if you can, 1
```

Comment: @msg varchar(200); also give same error please can you give me simple example

Comment: declare @msg varchar(50) this is ok for mssql but i want to learn same on mysql

Comment: every rdms has its own ways

Comment: thanks can you share me link where i can learn that . because i want to understand why := is used

Comment: that is also in the handbook https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html  but you don't need th : it is i write a lot of procedures and complicated sql statements and  so every body knows that is a adeclaration.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare variables only inside routines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DECLARE only in stored procedures. Here is a simple example of passing two variables to a stored procedure and declaring one variable inside the stored procedure

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`myslq_user`@`%` PROCEDURE `createRecord`(IN _name NVARCHAR(255), IN _userID int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE val INT DEFAULT 0;
        INSERT INTO tbldata (Name, UserID, Value) VALUES (_name, _userID, val);
    END IF;
END
```